# Excel sheet for Julia app?

Tags: excel, vba, julia

I have been using [Julia-Lang](http://julialang.org/) in the last 2 years for it's simplicity and high performance on scientific calculations. Besides the many ways to communicate with Julia, now I'm wondering about a possibility to use MS-Excel sheets as user interface for Julia apps. I think in this way user can simply enters inputs in Excel cells and see results over there, also by the way creating visual elements of custom style using already familiar environment of office will be straightforward. I am curious what facilities there are for linking Excel sheets with Julia.

So:

- What facilities are out there for linking MS-Excel or general speaking VBA and Julia?

Comment: It's not a problem of VBA. The problem lays in calling into native DLLs in which Julia should expose its API (Julia wouldn't be ever written in managed code). If it is possible then the rest is possible.

Comment: You could try going through a python/excel bridge like datanitro and then use a pyjulia bridge. But as a project, I would consider making a julia/libreoffice interface, perhaps by wrapping the UNO C++ bridge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia Computing offers [JuliaInXL](http://juliacomputing.com/products) for doing what you're asking.